# The method returns null pointer exception the null pinter is from serialized objects, I couldn't figure out the error yet

Tags: java, arraylist, deserialization

**This method is in a class without implementing serializable interface**

```
   public String FindVetsMedicalAppointments(String id){   MedicalBooking.getInstance().deserializeMedicalBooking();
    for (int i = 0; i < MedicalBooking.mediBookings.size(); i++) {
        MedicalBooking.getInstance().deserializeMedicalBooking();
        if(MedicalBooking.mediBookings.get(i).getVetId().equals(id)){
            System.out.println(MedicalBooking.getInstance().mediBookings.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
    return "END OF APPOINTMENTS";
 }
```

**This method is in a class implementing serializable interface**

```
  public void deserializeMedicalBooking(){
    try{
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Medical Appointments.txt");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
    mediBookings = (ArrayList<MedicalBooking>) in.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException i) {}
}
```

Comment: This is not only about null pointer exception, this occurs due to serialization. Take this into consideration

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Where do you get exception, post the stack trace

Comment: Pragnani Kinnera, I am trying to serialize an object of medical appointment into a text file using an array list, In the gui I am retrieving the object's value to be displayed to the vet. But when I call this method it gives me the Null pointer exception

Comment: You might want to put something in the empty catch block...

Comment: Still getting the same error message Andersen